# Correlation matrix for uncorrelated parameter estimates

Tags: correlation, covariance, definition

I have a set of $n$ parameter estimates. How can I understand if they are correlated or uncorrelated?
I guess I should calculate the correlation matrix. How is it exactly defined in terms of the covariance matrix? I knew this formula, but I am asking for confirmation of validity of it:

${C}_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{V_{\alpha \beta}}{\sqrt{V_{\alpha \alpha} V_{\beta \beta}}}$

where $C_{\alpha \beta}$ is the correlation matrix and $V_{\alpha \beta}$ the covariance matrix. How should the correlation matrix look like if the estimates are UNCORRELATED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be close to identity! Since uncorrelated terms have a low correlation, the off diagonal term will be close to zero. However, the correlation of a variable to itself is always 1.

If you use R:

```
uncorrelatedData <- matrix(data = rnorm(n = 100),ncol = 5)
cor(uncorrelatedData)

uncorrelatedData <- matrix(data = rnorm(n = 1000),ncol = 5)
cor(uncorrelatedData)
```